# Will a contiguous, low-Re, low-Ca, liquid body always become a sphere at zero gravity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

Let's assume zero gravity, zero initial speed everywhere, $Re \ll 1$ and $Ca \ll 1$

Will such a liquid body always become a sphere or will it sometimes split?

Formally speaking, I'm talking about

$$
\lim_{viscosity -> \infty} \lim_{t -> \infty} ShapeAtTime(t) 
$$

(Sufficiently high viscosity will also limit $Ca$, even though it is not directly in the expression)

I think it helps to think about this kind of experiment, but with an hourglass-like shape: Will its neck widen or expand at zero gravity?

[image: pitchdrop]

Comment: I think if you add the "no vibrational or rotational energy" caveat it would remain a sphere. If it is vibrating or rotating depending on the cohesion of the atoms it might break up into smaller ones.

Comment: @annav Added 0 initial speed as an assumption (and we already have high viscosity), but please note that I'm not assuming that the initial shape is already a sphere.

Comment: more spheres=more surface

Comment: Not sure high viscosity allows you to neglect inertia?

Comment: If its viscosity were infinite, its shape wouldn't change.  What do you think would happen if it had non-infinite viscosity, but the object were as big as the earth?  What effect do you think gravity would have if the object split into smaller spheres?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I hope my footnote clarifies things

Comment: wouldn't it be possible, given some weird initial shape of the contiguous blob, that it collapses and **spins**?  given any non-spherical initial shape, there is some potential energy in there.  where does that potential energy go?  (and, of course, if it **does** spin, it ain't gonna be perfectly spherical.)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson *wouldn't it be possible that it collapses and spins?* No : angular momentum conservation

Comment: yup, yer right.

Comment: @JMLCarter high viscosity => low-Re and low velocity, which in turn means low-Ca.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the initial fluid blob had symmetric dumb-bell shape, then fluid pressure will be higher at its waist, and there will be flow from waist region to the two bulging regions, resulting in breakup into (at least) two smaller droplets (read up [Rayleigh-Plateau instability](https://www.princeton.edu/~stonelab/Teaching/Oren%20Breslouer%20559%20Final%20Report.pdf)). In other words, even if velocity is zero everywhere initially at $t=0$, you can always set up a situation where pressure gradient is *not* zero everywhere inside the fluid, resulting in a flow for $t>0$ and thus possible breakup. You can always have a flow so far as viscosity is finite, no matter how high, and this alone cannot prevent breakup.

Comment: *you can always set up a situation ... so far as viscosity is finite*   Your argument is: "for any given viscosity > 0 we can choose a shape such that ...". In other words, you are talking about a *limit* (math) over shapes, which isn't in the question (the shape is finite, viscosity isn't)

Comment: Cant say I fully understand your comment. Dumb-bell shape is a shape, not a limit of some sequence of shapes (although it can be set up as such). The shape is finite, yes. As viscosity $\to\infty$, so does the time required for break up (as far as I can see).

Comment: It's futile to try to explain infinitesimals in a tweet-like comment, but let me try: Overly simply put, you don't get to choose a shape in response to my viscosity. I get to choose the viscosity in response to your shape -- That's the meaning of the first "limit" in the question.

Comment: @MaxB I don't think he's trying to set the limits of your question.  He's telling you a situation that may occur and is laying out the assumptions.  There is a condition that he is stating for this to occur.  It is up to you to decide if it properly answers your question.  I don't think he did anything wrong.  In fact, you say he's talking about a limit and reference it to math over shapes.  If anything his answer is specifically about real scenarios _up to_ the limit where the math becomes more abstract than his answer (I. E. Literal infinite viscosity, at infinite time).

Comment: @MaxB The same dumbbell shape works for every finite viscosity.

Comment: @MaxB Choose whatever viscosity you want. There will still be breakup in the dumb bell shaped drop. If you are going to take the limit viscosity $\to\infty$, then as I have said before time for breakup will tend to infinity as well. In fact as Chester Miller has correctly pointed out, in the limit as viscosity tends to infinity (while driving forces remaining the same) internal relative motion within the fluid tends to zero, and consequently so does change in shape of the blob.

Answer (score 3):

If the object is infinitely viscous (and non-volatile, so that it can't evaporate), it will never change shape.